# Zend Expressive nested application

Tags: mezzio

I'm trying to use zend expressive nested application, so I'm following this blog post :
https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-03-15-nested-middleware-in-expressive.html

The problem seems to be in the Middleware factory:

```
class CreateBookMiddlewareFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $nested = new Application(
          $container->get(RouterInterface::class),
          $container
        );

        $nested->pipe(AuthenticationMiddleware::class);
        $nested->pipe(ContentValidationMiddleware::class);
        $nested->pipe(BodyParamsMiddleware::class);
        $nested->pipe(BookValidationMiddleware::class);
        $nested->pipe(CreateBookMiddleware::class);

        return $nested;
    }
}
```

I don't get how `CreateBookMiddleware` could be added to the pipe here as we are in its Factory. So piping it will call the factory, create a new nested application, which will call the factory, which will create another nested application...

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in /var/www/project/vendor/zendframework/zend-stratigility/src/Next.php on line
   158
```

Is there something I'm not getting right from this blog post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named the factory `CreateBookMiddlewareFactory`. And then inside `__invoke` you have `$nested->pipe(CreateBookMiddleware::class);`. It depends on your config, but usually CreateBookMiddlewareFactory would be the factory for CreateBookMiddleware. So it's stuck in a loop because it keeps creating itself.

As you have the exact same code as in the blogpost, I'm guessing it's an error in that blog post. I think it should have been like in the last delegator factory example: without the last `$nested->pipe(CreateBookMiddleware::class);`.

I've notified the author of the blog post.

Edit: The blog post is updated with this fix:

```
namespace Acme\Api;

use Acme\AuthenticationMiddleware;
use Acme\ContentNegotiationMiddleware;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\Expressive\Application;
use Zend\Expressive\Helper\BodyParams\BodyParamsMiddleware;
use Zend\Expressive\Router\RouterInterface;

class CreateBookMiddlewareFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $nested = new Application(
          $container->get(RouterInterface::class),
          $container
        );

        $nested->pipe(AuthenticationMiddleware::class);
        $nested->pipe(ContentValidationMiddleware::class);
        $nested->pipe(BodyParamsMiddleware::class);
        $nested->pipe(BookValidationMiddleware::class);

        // If dependencies are needed, pull them from the container and pass
        // them to the constructor:
        $nested->pipe(new CreateBookMiddleware());

        return $nested;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I accepted @xtreamwayz answer for the clarification. But here's how I made it work:

```
class CreateBookMiddlewareFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $nested = new Application(
          $container->get(RouterInterface::class),
          $container
        );

        $nested->pipe($container->get(AuthenticationMiddleware::class));
        $nested->pipe($container->get(ContentValidationMiddleware::class));
        $nested->pipe($container->get(BodyParamsMiddleware::class));
        $nested->pipe($container->get(BookValidationMiddleware::class));
        // instanciate the new class, so it will not call the factory again
        $nested->pipe(new CreateBookMiddleware());

        return $nested;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly how it's fixed in the post just now: https://github.com/zendframework/zf3-web/commit/2ae14d151e512b13506c4f854ad6a811d9a74af0